# [16.04]Unable to run unity-control-center and gnome-control-center because of undefined symbol

Tags: unity, gnome, software-center

when running unity-control-center i get:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: wl_proxy_marshal_constructor_versioned
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-control-center-1/panels/libinfo.so
```

and when running gnome-control-center I get:

```
gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: wl_proxy_marshal_constructor_versioned
```

and when I start it through the UI I simply get a popup that says something like "system error, would you like to report?"

I have no idea when this started happening since I haven't used the control center in a while. and any fix I've tried has been fruitless but I've only tried reinstalling.

any help is welcome!

here is the output from "apt-cache policy libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37" (translated from swedish to english since my system is in swedish, sorry)

```
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:
      Installed:    2.20.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
      Candidate:    2.20.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
      Version table:
      *** 2.20.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
          500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
          500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      2.10.9-1ubuntu1 500
          500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
N: Ignoring file ”00trustcdrom.backup.20171209” in the directory”/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/” because it has an invalid file extension
N: Ignoring file ”00aptitude.backup.20171209” in the directory ”/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/” because it has an invalid file extension
N: Ignoring file ”01autoremove-kernels.backup.20171209” in the directory ”/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/” because it has an invalid file extension
```

and here is the output for "sudo apt-get update" (also translated)

```
Good:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Read:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]                       
Good:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bit-team/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                    
Good:4 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                        
Good:5 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease               
Good:6 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy InRelease                                         
Read:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [67,5 kB]
Read:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [72,6 kB]
Read:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [107 kB]
Read:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [142 kB]
Read:11 https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main xenial InRelease [3 651 B]
Ign:11 https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main xenial InRelease
downloaded 499 kB in 1s (464 kB/s)
reading packet lists… done
N: Ignoring file ”00trustcdrom.backup.20171209” in the directory”/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/” because it has an invalid file extension
N: Ignoring file ”00aptitude.backup.20171209” in the directory ”/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/” because it has an invalid file extension
N: Ignoring file ”01autoremove-kernels.backup.20171209” in the directory ”/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/” because it has an invalid file extension
W: GPG-Error: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main xenial InRelease: 
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key isn't available: NO_PUBKEY 56A3DEF863961D39
W: The repository 'https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Have you installed from some PPA that pulls in a different version of webkit perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is or how I would know if that was the case. I'm not a very experienced linux user. I'm willing to provide stuff that I've done that could have resulted in this error but I have no idea of what would be relevant.

Comment: When I try and update ubuntu with sudo "apt-get dist-upgrade" I get an error that says that some datafiles for some of the packages failed to download. but that is for flashplugin-installer... so idk.

Comment: When you run `sudo apt-get update` are any of the URLs for a domain other than `archive.ubuntu.com` or `archive.canonical.com`?

Comment: Also please [edit] your question and include the output of `apt-cache policy libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37`.

Comment: I've copied the putput from both the "apt-cache policy libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37" and the "sudo apt-get update" commands into my original question.

Comment: OK. So you've got a PPA, and two externally hosted repositories installed. And it looks like the webkit library package is correct.  The PPA doesn't include anything I see that should cause this, nor do the mono or intel repositories. Have you installed anything from source or manually from some other third party location?

Comment: possibly. since I'm still new to ubuntu It's very much learning by trail and error. the server is a plex server with a few supporting programs and scripts. but as far as I'm aware everything that I have on my computer is either from a git project and widely used or through the ubuntu default repositories.

Comment: I solved it. thank you for having a look at the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by restoring from backup the file

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37
```

that was mentioned in the error message. The file that broke unity-control-center were a link to a file called

```
libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.28.2
```

while my old file and now working, is a link to the file

```
libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.14.10
```

booth files exists and the link wasn't broken. It was just the wrong version of the file that was needed. what the file does, I have no idea but this is were this nightmare, hopefully, ends.

Comment: I have a similar problem (with different packages, though:  libgtk-3.so.0 and libgiomm-2.4.so.1). How do you see the links from libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 to libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.28.2 or libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.14.10?